# Why am I not able to get authenticated user id?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, async-await, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to get current logged in user if but not able to fetch it, whats the problem here

```
String uid;
   FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
Future returnuid() async {
    FirebaseUser user = await auth.currentUser();
     uid = user.uid;
     }
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    returnuid();
     return StreamBuilder(
        stream: Firestore.instance.collection('UserData').document(uid).snapshots(),
```

I think the problem here is i am not awaiting returnuid() but how can i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
 Stream<DocumentSnapshot> getData()async*{
     FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
     yield* Firestore.instance.collection('UserData').document(user.uid).snapshots();
  }
```

Then just call this method in the `StreamBuilder`:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return StreamBuilder(
        stream:getData()
```